# A question on Monte Carlo

Tags: self-study, monte-carlo

We simulate $E(\exp(z))$ by Monte Carlo method,where $z\sim{}N(0,1)$. For sample sizes $2^{16}$ and $2^{17}$, the variance errors are 0.00531 and 0.00364, respectively. The ratio of these two errors is approximately $1.5$. My questions are:

(1) What information can we learn from this ratio?

(2) Why should the ratio approach $\sqrt 2$ as the sample size approaches infinity?

Comment: This looks rather like bookwork. If this is for some subject, would please add the self-study tag? What do you mean by "the variance error"? Are you referring to the standard error of the sample variance, the standard error of the sample mean, or to some other quantity? Can you be more explicit about how those numbers were calculated?

Comment: @Glen_b I am studying Monte Carlo method by reading An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation.My questions come from the last paragraph of the section 15.2 on page 144.I don't know if you could have a look at this book.The author,Desmond J.Higham, gave an computational example on the simulation of E(exp(z)).On the analysis of the results,he indicated the ratio of those erros.But I don't understand what information can we get from this ratio.

Comment: It's still unclear. What is the definition of the "variance errors" you refer to, including the definition of any terms this quantity depends on in turn?

Comment: Okay, I managed to induce Google books to let me look at a couple of pages. On the basis of those pages, if that book was mine, I'd strew garlic plants about, stake its shrivelled heart and burn it with fire. Judging from the last several books I've seen from them, Cambridge appear to be on a kick to publish books containing the most bizarre and idiosyncratic terminology and the some of the worst available explanations of simple concepts (and I'm - not by choice - teaching from one of them).

Comment: @Glen_b can I give you a +1 for making me laugh this morning?

Comment: This question was cross-posted at http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8610/a-question-on-monte-carlo-method.  Hebe, please either delete the duplicate question or else supply there a summary of the answers you receive here.

Comment: @whuber I will give the link there :-)

Comment: Hebe, please see [this section of help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which contains the following: *cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. **Choose one best location to post your question**. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated*.  (Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having had a quick look; you may consider this first part of my answer a form of technical book review based on about 3 pages of the following book:

Desmond Higham (2004)
*An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation*, Mathematics, Stochastics and Computation, Volume 13, Cambridge University Press.

It appears that this is the set up in the book:

$X_1, X_2 ...$ are (quote) "random variables" with mean $a$ and variance $b^2$; $a_M$ is the mean of the first $M$ $X$'s (okay, it makes sense to here, though the use of $a$ is odd because population parameters are more conventionally Greek letters). Now things get bizarre $b_M$ is, as defined, the *sample variance*. That is, $X_i$ has apparently but subtly changed from a *random variable* to an *observation*, presumably starting at least back at the definition of $a_M$.

So that's got no chance of being anything but confusing. Let's start again with less misleading notation and terminology. Let me set up some terms, so at least I have some idea what I am talking about:

> Let $X_1, X_2 ...$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with common mean $\theta$ and variance $\tau^2$.
>
> Let $x_1, x_2 ...$ denote *observations on those random variables*. Let $\bar{x}_m$ be the sample mean of the first $m$ $x$'s and let $s^2_m$ be the sample variance of the first $m$ $x$'s.

(The author confused those two things together. Not okay.)

The author then invokes the Central Limit Theorem to say that $\bar{x}_m - \theta$ should be approximately $\sim N(0,\tau^2/m)$. Not technically the right way to do it, but I will say okay, up to some caveats and handwaving.

He now calls $\tau/\sqrt{m}$ 'the standard error'. It is in fact *[the standard error of the sample mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Standard_deviation_of_the_mean)*. Anyway, let's move on.

He now refers to $s^2_m$ as "the variance approximation". In fact, right now it's just the sample variance, but of course, the sample variance (under certain conditions) will in large samples be an approximation for $\tau^2$. He has the cart before the horse.

He now implies he can use $s_m$ for $\tau$ in his earlier discussion about the distribution of the deviation in the mean. Well, yes, but you have to do it right. By invoking Slutsky's theorem, we can have that $(\bar{x}_m - \theta)/(s_m/\sqrt{m})$ will go to a standard normal as $m \rightarrow \infty$. Which isn't quite what he said, but let's allow him some significantly more vigorous handwaving.

Now, finally, we get the definition of "the variance error". Translating, it's $|s^2_m - \tau^2|$.  Okay, so what he actually means is the absolute deviation of the sample variance from the population value. Let's denote that by $d_m$.

The conclusion of the review and translation: The author is trying to explain something important, but did a very poor job of it

--

So now the question is, if $m_1$ is some large sample size, and $m_2$ is say $2m_1$, if we compute $d_{m_1}/d_{m_2}$, why does that ratio approach $\sqrt 2$ and what does that tell us?

As the author explained a few pages before this point, the variance of an average of iid random variables decreases with the sample size. This is true also of the sample variance, itself a kind of average (an average of squared differences - I must excuse my own little bit of handwaving of details to do with the difference between $m-1$ and $m$ on the denominator; this can be made technically correct and still go through). As such,
its own variance decreases with increasing $m$. The quantity $(s_m^2 - \tau^2)/(1/\sqrt{m})$ is (as $m$ becomes large) itself going to have approximately a normal distribution with mean zero and constant variance.

So, if $r_1= |s_{m_1}^2 - \tau^2|/(1/\sqrt{m_1})$ and $r_2$ is similarly defined, then $r_1/r_2$ will (again, by invoking Slutsky!) converge  to 1.

Now $d_1/d_2 = \sqrt{m_2/m_1}\cdot r_1/r_2$. So that converges to $\sqrt 2$.

As for what it tells you, merely that the payback for twice the work isn't twice as much accuracy; the sample variance approaches the population variance in the same fashion as the sample mean does - fairly slowly, as $1/\sqrt{m}$.

Comment: I appreciate your attention to my questions and your detailed interpretation on those confusing parts of that book!

Comment: Hi Hebe - I discovered a typo in my definition of $r$, which I had carried through a couple of steps (now fixed). The conclusion was right, but that may have caused you some confusion.

Comment: Glen_b, you are great! I tried to delete my post at Quante SE,but I didn't find the way.

Answer (score 0):

Well an important question is how many samples do you need to half the sampling error.  essentially by the central limit theorem, the sample mean, has standard error sigma/sqrt(N), [where sigma is the "true" population standard deviation]

so all the ratio is telling you is that doubling the number of samples reduces the error by only 1/sqrt(2)...

Comment: you don't need the central limit theorem for that: each item is a sample from an independent (identically distributed) random variable. It's sufficient to apply the result for the variance of the sum of independent random variables, and then scale.

Comment: of course - but the OP is asking basic "applied" questions - not for mathematical proofs... so CLT is telling you that your sample mean converges to a normal dstribution with mean =population mean and standard deviation=population standard deviation/sqrt(N)

Comment: Your answer was correct, but you don't need the distribution of the result to get the standard deviation, and I've seen the $\sqrt{2}$ ratio explained in simple terms many times without using the CLT.

Comment: belated apologies if the tone of my comment was too judgemental / caused any offence, it would have been better phrased as a suggestion.